# list directory contents if directory path is specified in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, static, filesystems

I am trying to simply serve static files on my node.js server. I can do this easily if the path in url bar is linking to a static file. however, if im trying to list directory contents, i need to use node.js filesystem calls. i am able to list directory contents, but i want to navigate each level and fetch contents as needed. 
similar to how apache's default functionality if there is no 'index.html' inside the directory, it will list all contents.

[apache list directory contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKe74.png)

how do i make a simple html page that lists the directory contents, and are clickable to navigate to and serve?

specifically i have a logs folder that i want to access. and inside that folder are sub directories, and scattered various logs.

heres what i've tried so far.

```
//inside server.js
// serve any static file inside my logs folder
app.use('/logs', express.static('logs'));
```

---

```
// routes.js
var logger = require('../controllers/s3logs');

app.get('/listlogs', function (req, res) {
        res.render('logpage', {logList : logger.findFiles()} );
    });
```

---

```
// controller s3logs.js
exports.findFiles = function(path)
exports.findFiles = function (path) {

if (path==undefined)
{
    path='logs';
}

var fileArray = fs.readdirSync(path); //get array of objects inside root dir
var fileObjArray = [];


// iterate through each file found in the directory
// find stats, make an obj, and push to new array

fileArray.forEach(function(item, index){
    const pathToItem =    path+'/'+item ;
    const stats = fs.statSync(pathToItem);

    var fileObj = {
        "name": item,
        "path": pathToItem,
        "isDir": stats.isDirectory(),
        "size": stats.size,
        "modified": stats.mtime
    };

    fileObjArray.push(fileObj);

    });

return fileObjArray;
};
```

---

```
//logpage.html
<body>
<ul>
    {% for file in loglist %}
    <li {% if loop.first %} class="first"{% endif %}>
        <a href= {{ file.path }}>{{ file.name }}</a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
```

this code is working, but i need to resolve the path to traverse another directory deeper. to call my function again. I can solve this through a post request, but i feel like this is getting too complicated already...
any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you trying to re-invent the wheel? https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-directory

Comment: I ended up using serve-static middleware. it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used serve static middleware to serve my own custom html if path specified is a directory.

```
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');


// serve static logs files
var serve = serveStatic('logs');

app.use('/logs', serve, function (req, res) {
    // console.log(req)
    res.render('logpage', {logList:s3logger.findFiles(req.originalUrl), currentPath: req.originalUrl} );
});
```